# passing var to a jquery function

Tags: jquery

I have a form which has multiple input fields, and 3 main options. depending on what option the user selects I want to be able to hide non relevant fields and show relevant ones. please can some one advice me on how I may achieve this.

my second question is each field has some examples text next to it, so once again I want to be able to change the text depending on what the user selects. so far what i have done is display each text in a `<p>` tag next to the field and I have given it two classes. one is static which styles the text (.htxt) and the other is either .option1 .option2 .option3. so when a user clicks option one i want to hide all option2 and 3 text and show only 1. so i have something like this so far

```
    $(".link").click(function () {
        $(".hTxt").hide("slow");
        // this gets the id of the link (option 1, option2, option3)
        target = $(this).attr("id");
        $(".hTxt ." + target).show("slow");
    });
```

this doesn't seem to work, I was wondering if any one could help me out with this.

the html for one of the text looks like so

```
<p class="hTxt option1" >help me</p>
```

while the link calling it looks like so

```
<a class="link" id="option1">this is option1</a>
```

Comment: could you please post a sample of your html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are saving an id but selecting a class with it; try like this instead

```
$(".link").click(function () {
        $("#.hTxt").hide("slow");
        // this gets the id of the link (option 1, option2, option3)
        target = $(this).attr("id");
        $(".link #" + target).show("slow");   /* #id VS .class */
    });
```

and here you do a mix:  `$("#.hTxt").hide("slow");`

if its a class->  `$(".hTxt").hide("slow");`

if its an id  ->   `$("#hTxt").hide("slow");`

-EDIT-

i Am guessing by your comment that hTxt is a class, so please try like this and let me know

```
$(".link").click(function () {
        $(".hTxt").hide("slow");
        // this gets the id of the link (option 1, option2, option3)
        target = $(this).attr("id");
        $(".link #" + target).show("slow");   
    });
```

Comment: But post the relevant HTML so can help you better

Comment: i have the relevant changes, in theory when the user clicks one of the options, it should first hide all .hTxt tags then only show .hTxt .option1 2 or 3

Comment: please looks at my edit, the last line does not seem to work, i have  $(".link ." + target).show("slow"); because the value of target has 'option1' which correlated to the p tag classes.

Comment: please post HTML; i can't guess it

Comment: i solved it by doing this for the end line $("." + target).show("slow");

Comment: OK, That's is because you have id's referencing classnames; again, without the HTML it was very hard to tell, but i am glad you solved